# Как в конструкторе наследника выбрать конструктора родителя в зависимости от параметра?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

Я знаю, что в конструкторе "наследника" первой строчкой обязан быть вызов конструктора родителя. Возник вопрос: а что делать, ежели вдруг (каким - то корявым путем) в конструкторе наследника необходим выбор конструктора родителя, от какого - либо внешнего параметра?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартными методами внутри одного конструктора вызвать разные родительски конструкторы невозвможно. Однако если есть доступ к изменению класса-родителя можно сделать `protected` мето `initialize`, вызывать его из конструкторов, и сделать отдельный конструктор который не будет его вызывать. Тогда можно будет выбирать способ вызова из класса-наследника путём вызова пустого конструктора, и ручного вызова `initialize`.

Comment: не совсем понял, как я понял вы предлагаете , создать дополнительную функцию , которая будет далее формировать объект и ограничить к ней доступ ?

Comment: @СергейКуренчук Да.

Answer (score 5):

Явный вызов конструктора родителя не является обязательным, если у родительского класса есть конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров).

Так как конструкторы родителя должны отличаться друг от друга по количеству параметров и по типу параметров, то при вызове конструктора родителя из наследника будет выбран, тот конструктор, который подходит по параметрам переданным при вызове.

```
class Parent {
    public Parent() {}
    public Parent(int i) {}
    public Parent(String a) {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
        super(1); // выбран конструктор Parent(int i)
    }

    public Child(int i) {
       // выбран конструктор Parent()
       // какой-то код без вызова super
    }

    public Child(String s) {
        super(s); // выбран конструктор Parent(String a)
    }
}
```

Comment: Я наверно очень искривляю логику хорошего стиля кодирования. Вопрос был не в перегрузке. А в  выборе конструктора , в зависимости от ситуаций (от анализа параметров конструктора - наследника). Но в любом случае спасибо за столь развернутый ответ :)

Comment: вы хотите добавить логику до вызова конструктора? и с помощью этой логики вызывать разные конструкторы в разных случаях?

Comment: да, это интересует

Comment: а какую задачу вы решаете? зачем вам это надо?

Comment: Лишь учебные изыскания. Пример ? Хм, возможно два различных конструктора , кои инициализирует ссылку на объект. В зависимости от флага, ссылка инициализируется либо родителем или наследником . И далее вызов различных функций. Пример конечно вытянутый,  сложно пример придумать :)

Comment: вы описываете не задачу, а решение. всегда можно придумать решение, которое невозможно реализовать средствами java. но если взять задачу, то можно найти хорошее решение средствами java.